# Javascript select part of page / canvas and convert it as an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas on my page with some Content in it. The canvas contains like a pdf file Images and some text.

Now I want to implement a functionality so that I can select a specific part of the canvas (the Images) and save them separatly as an Image.

It would look something like window's snipping tool app.
I could not found a library which may help accomplishing so that how should I begin with this?

Comment: you would draw the region to another fresh, pre-sized canvas, and export that to an image.

Comment: @dandavis Sounds good but how do I Programm the mouse pull stuff?

Comment: via drawImage(). it accepts the "corner" coords of the source image. the harder part will be drawing a temporary rectangle around the existing content to indicate selections. i would use an old-school (non-HTML5) drag and drop routine to move floating corners around the top left and bottom right, then you can turn those offsets into params for drawImage. it is a bit involved, tbh